# PROC compiler fails for connect with prior in case using 'NOCYCLE'

Tags: sql, c, oracle11g, proc

I am very new to PROC and I was compiling following query in .pc file,

```
`
SELECT * FROM CUST
WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = :sqli_customer_id
START WITH SUBSCRIBER_NO = :sqli_subscriber_no
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR PRV_CTN = SUBSCRIBER_NO
ORDER BY ROWNUM DESC
`
```

following query fails to compile in PROC complier 
but when I remove the **`NOCYCLE`** from query, file gets successfully compiled.

I get following error with `NOCYCLE`:

```
PCC-S-02201, Encountered the symbol "PRIOR" when expecting one of the following:
   = ( * < > + - / . @ ^= | != <= >= <> at, not, between, in, is, like, day, hour, minute, month, second, year, 
The symbol "*" was substituted for "PRIOR" to continue.
```

`

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Thanks,

Nitin T.

Comment: It's not clear what this has to do with `C`.

Comment: Which version of Oracle (and Pro\*C if different) are you using? The `nocycle` clause wasn't added until 10g, I believe. If you're on that version or above, are you restricting the syntax available via the Pro\*C `dbms` command line option?